# How can I get the amount of consecutive sub strings of an object in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example, how would I make the y value in this:

```py
>>>x = input("Enter some numbers: ")
0000101 001 001 11001
>>>x = x.split()
```

Which makes `y = ["0000", " " "00", " ", "00", " ", ""]` because the first thing in x starts with 4 0s, the second and third start with 2 0s, and the last one doesn't start with any 0s.

Sorry for any confusion, let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Shouldn't y be `['0000', '00', '00', '']`?

Comment: Yeah, `y = ["0000", " " "00", " ", "00", " ", ""]` is absurd. Please that a proper look at that. @schwobaseggl It is valid python though..

Comment: @JohnColeman It's not homework, I am making something voluntarily, and I haven't done anything yet because i don't know how you would do it

Comment: @schwobaseggl I want it to show that it has spaces for when I join them

Comment: @TheRealTengri The spaces are quite artificial and nnot part of the question. Your `x`, for starters, does not contain spaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile),

```
from itertools import takewhile

s = "0000101 001 001 11001"

result = [''.join(takewhile(lambda x: x == "0", chunk)) for chunk in s.split()]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['0000', '00', '00', '']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

x = "0000101 001 001 11001".split()
# ['0000101', '001', '001', '11001']

y = [re.match('(0*)', s).group(1) for s in x]
# ['0000', '00', '00', '']
```

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) only matches at the beginning of the string, and the parentheses `()` mark the first and only [group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) of 0 or more `'0'`.

Answer (score 1):

`lstrip()` is useful:

```
[len(s)-len(s.lstrip('0')) for s in x.split()]
```

evaluates to

```
[4, 2, 2, 0]
```

and

```
['0'*(len(s)-len(s.lstrip('0'))) for s in x.split()]
```

evaluates to

```
['0000', '00', '00', '']
```